# Having only one die +Gremlins

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

If a pc has the disadvantage "gremlins" (which results in him needing less 1s for a glitch when dealing with tech), and needs to roll on something which results in him having only one die (e.g. Computers + Logic, the pc has no points in Computers and 2 in Logic, resulting in 1 die), does he automatically roll a (critical) glitch because normally he would need to roll a single 1, but "gremlins" reduces this number by it's level, making it 0 or even less? Is there anything about this mentioned in the rule book(s)? I am not strictly asking for RAW here, because I don't know if that is even covered by the rules.

Comment: It probably sounds completely unimportant, but this is a serious attempt at clarification because I may or may not have an answer depending on your answer:  Does this character use guns and/or cyberware?  Or are we talking about a tech-eschewing character, like a sword adept or a nature mage?

Comment: A mage using a sword and bow, but she is a hermetic mage and not strongly against using guns at least, that was the situation where the question came up initially.

Comment: This mage is going to have a bad time using his commlink to call his mother...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** is the short and quick answer.

The **Gremlins** "upgrades" the innabilty of the character to use technology, so for a normal guy with gremlins it's an annoyance, but for such a tech negated guy, **Gremlins** is going to give him some pain in the ass.

If you use it as in RAW, the story ends here, but keep in mind that it can be exploited by the characters, since someone can have a dice pool of 2 and take the 4 level **Gremlins** and have the same effects that having level 1, totally dumping his tech skills forever, the level 4 only becoming an issue as he grows up tech skills.

You can house-rule something like when the character rolls 1 he must roll again 1D6, and rolling under his **Gremlins** level (1-4 in max **Gremlin** level) the glitch becomes critical, this way a level 1 **Gremlin** is verty glitchy, but not very critical, but the "exploited" **Gremlins** 4 - dicepool 2 character would end in critical glitching most of the time.

@Gatherer818 asked about if he using cyberware, but this is not a problem since last part of Gremlins say:

> **Page 81 Core rulebook (Gremlins)**:
>
> The effect only applies to external equipment
> and does not affect cyberware, bioware, or other implants.

**Edit:** But the use of guns can matter as it's external equipment...